# Calculate ball rotation angle based on marker position

Tags: math, rotation, geometry, angle

I am using camera to trace one black marker on blue ball as shown in image below.

[image: Blue ball with black marker]

I can detect marker position on top of ball image reliably but would need to know 
how to calculate ball rotation angles based on marker location.

When marker is in the middle as shown both angles should be 0 degrees. When marker is only half visible at left edge as shown horizontal angle should be -90 degrees. I understand calculating angles from 2D-image is non-linear, near the edge similar movement in pixels means bigger change in rotation than in the middle but I just can't come up with the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotation about vertical axis:

```
Phi  = ArcSin((Marker.X - Center.X) / Radius)
```

In general, if you grab initial point with 2D coordinates (x0, y0) at the front surface of ball manipulator with radius 1 and drag it ti end point (x1,y1), then you rotate direction vector

```
d0 = (x0, y0, Sqrt(1 - x0^2 - y0^2))
to
d1 = (x1, y1, Sqrt(1 - x1^2 - y1^2))
```

What to do with these vectors? I depends on what approach are you going to use for rotation

Comment: I understand now rotation about vertical axis, thanks. I guess same can be applied for horizontal axis as well. Not sure about second part, what is the range for x0,y0,x0 and x1? I guess 1-x0^2-y0^2 needs to be always positive for sqrt to work?

Comment: Yes, just change X to Y

Comment: For `Radius=1` ranges are `-1..1` for  x and y, sum of squares not bigger that 1, and positive `0..1` for z - coordinate (we can see only front hemisphere)

Comment: @MBo I prefer to use `atan2` is `arcsin` implementation more precise or it does not matter which to use?

Comment: @Spektre Note -we need ball rotation, not full-circle angle for given point.  I don't think that precision is important here. Just marker X-position has sine law dependence on rotation about vertical axis, that is why I've used arcsin. Also range `-Pi/2..Pi/2 ` is suitable here.